# HttpRequestMessage with Mltipart/Form-data Connection Closing Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

I am attempting to post some XML to a web server. To do so I have to use the HTTP protocol, Post method, a multipart/form-data Content-Type, with 1 parameter called "xmlinfo" containing the XML I am uploading. The server uses basic authentication.

I keep getting the following error message:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the Request ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I'm not sure why this is happening because I do posts to this server else where without problem; however, these posts do not involve a multipart/form-data content-type. I am looking for advise on how to get around it.

The following is the function I am currently having problems with posting the xml to the server:

```
    public static async Task<Object> SaveXMLAsync(string xml)
    {
        Object strResult = String.Empty;

        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
            credentials.UserName = user;
            credentials.Password = password;
            handler.Credentials = credentials;

            using (var webClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                webClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ip);
                webClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, String.Format("{0}import/xml", ip)))
                {

                    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----MyBoundary"))
                    {
                        StringContent xmlContent = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                        content.Add(xmlContent, "xmlinfo");
                        request.Content = content;
                        request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
                        try
                        {
                            var response = await webClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, CancellationToken.None);
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                strResult = result.Result;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strResult = string.Format("Problem: {0}", response.RequestMessage);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            strResult = ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return strResult;
    }
```

Comment: Unknown if this is related, but you shouldn't block on `ReadAsStringAsync()`,

Comment: I don't even get to that line of code...

Comment: Well, when you do, it could deadlock depending on how you call this method.

Comment: What is the value for `ip` or, more specifically, does it also specify a port number?

Comment: I guess the server could be dropping the connection when it fails to process your request. Maybe try debugging the server-side application or checking any logs it may have.

Comment: @Biscuits there is no port necessary for the request. The HTTP server is listening on port 80. I cannot debug the server-side application as it is embedded into a piece of hardware.

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you for your insight into the ReadAsStringAsync method

Comment: I am still stuck on this. What is increasingly frustrating is that I am able to accomplish my task perfectly fine using curl but I cannot get this to work in my C# code within my app (without having to call out to the curl application) I am at a loss. I have tried multiple different approaches (using different http methods to do the request) and I can't get past this problem.